# R tidyr::pivot_longer() multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains several columns, as shown below:

[image]

I want to transform the data into a longer format with the names:
Trade Value, Position, Player Name, and Trend Value

Here's what I tried.... But the code tries to combine the Trend and Player Name columns.  How to have specify that those should be two separate columns represented by the same Position?

```
  Data_trend <-
    data %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(
      cols = !`Trade Value`,
      names_to = c("Position", "Player Name"),
      names_pattern = c("(.*).(.*)"),
    )
```

Thanks for you help!

Here's how to reproduce the data:

```
    data <- structure(list(`Trade Value` = c(79, 70.5, 68.5, 67.5, 64, 61, 
57.5, 57, 56.5, 56, 55, 54, 51.5, 51, 49.5, 48.5, 47, 43, 41, 
39.5, 39, 38.5, 38.5, 38, 35, 34.5, 33.5, 32, 30.5, 30), `Running Back.Player Name` = c("Christian McCaffrey", 
"Dalvin Cook", "Alvin Kamara", "", "", "Ezekiel Elliott", "Saquon Barkley", 
"", "Derrick Henry", "", "", "", "Nick Chubb", "Aaron Jones", 
"Jonathan Taylor", "", "", "", "Joe Mixon", "Antonio Gibson", 
"Austin Ekeler", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Clyde Edwards-Helaire", 
"J.K. Dobbins"), `Running Back.Trend` = c(0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 
0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0), `Wide Receiver.Player Name` = c("", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "Stefon Diggs", "Davante Adams", "", "Calvin Ridley", 
"Tyreek Hill", "", "", "", "", "DeAndre Hopkins", "", "", "", 
"A.J. Brown", "D.K. Metcalf", "Justin Jefferson", "", "Terry McLaurin", 
"", "Keenan Allen", "Allen Robinson II", "Mike Evans", ""), `Wide Receiver.Trend` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA), `Tight End.Player Name` = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Travis Kelce", "", 
"", "", "", "George Kittle", "", "", "", "", "", "Darren Waller", 
"", "", "", "", "", ""), `Tight End.Trend` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Quarterback.Player Name` = c("", 
"", "", "Patrick Mahomes II", "Josh Allen", "", "", "", "", "Kyler Murray", 
"", "", "", "", "Lamar Jackson", "Dak Prescott", "", "", "", 
"", "", "Russell Wilson", "", "", "Justin Herbert", "Aaron Rodgers", 
"", "", "", ""), Quarterback.Trend = c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another solution with a slightly leaner regex:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, 
               names_to = c("Position", ".value"), 
               names_pattern = c("([^\\.]+)\\.([^\\.]+)"))
```

The regex consists of three elements:

- `([^\\.]+)`: the first pattern to match - this is a negative character class allowing only characters that are **not** the period `.`
- `\\.`: the period, which here serves as the splitting element and which needs to be escaped as its a metacharacter
- `([^\\.]+)`: the second pattern to match - same explanation as above

**EDIT**:

A **much leaner** solution is with `names_sep`:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, 
               names_to = c("Position", ".value"), 
               names_sep = "\\.")
```

Comment: Very nice Mr. Ruehlemann. I'm taking regex in earnest so I hope to be learning from all the masters like you :)

Comment: Thanks for the praise. As regards your regex: I think you can trim it down to this: `"(\\D+)\\.(\\D+)"`

Comment: This is because `\\D`matches anything that's not a digit; hence it will also match `\\s` as a whitespace is not a digit.

Comment: Yes exactly. I will add it to my solution. I've been meaning to use non-capturing group syntax and was glad it worked here, maybe it was slightly too much for this simple case.

Comment: Even that works: `(.*)\\.(.*)`but like `(\\D+)\\.(\\D+)` it is much less rigorous than `([^\\.]+)\\.([^\\.]+)`.

Comment: Yes exactly! I think the second and third are more specific. I only have one question and would be grateful if you could answer it. In this structure `(\\D+(?:\\s\\D+)?)` where we define a non-capturing group as some optional matching within a capturing group do we need to also specify the presence by `?` at the end? I tried and without the `?` it doesn't work in the way it should. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Dear @AnoushiravanR I see you are really interested to learn regex in-depth. The way I see it, but I admit I may be wrong, using `(?:\\s\\D+)?` is not necessary - redundant, if you will -  as `\\D+` already covers strings such as `Trend` and `Player name`. What the non-capturing group does is it matches a concurrent pattern that is not stored and not outputted (similar to a lookaround).

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Ruehlemann, you are right. I also added your suggestion on the top of my solution. Thank you for taking your time to answer my question, hope I can return the favor :)

Answer (score 4):

As per suggestion by dear Mr. [Chris Ruehlemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8039978/chris-ruehlemann) here is a slightly leaner version of this solution:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(!`Trade Value`, names_to = c("Position", ".value"), 
               names_pattern = "(\\D+)\\.(\\D+)")

# A tibble: 120 x 4
   `Trade Value` Position      `Player Name`         Trend
           <dbl> <chr>         <chr>                 <dbl>
 1          79   Running Back  "Christian McCaffrey"     0
 2          79   Wide Receiver ""                       NA
 3          79   Tight End     ""                       NA
 4          79   Quarterback   ""                       NA
 5          70.5 Running Back  "Dalvin Cook"             0
 6          70.5 Wide Receiver ""                       NA
 7          70.5 Tight End     ""                       NA
 8          70.5 Quarterback   ""                       NA
 9          68.5 Running Back  "Alvin Kamara"            0
10          68.5 Wide Receiver ""                       NA
# ... with 110 more rows
```

You can use the following solution. Based on your column names I used the following regex structure:

- `\\D+` matches any non-digit characters including white spaces one or multiple times
  so first capture group `(\\D+)` matches a name like `Running Back`.
- `(?:\\s\\D+)` this is a non-capturing group I used which has a `(?: ...)` structure indicating an optional pattern, here it is a white space `\\s` followed by a number of non-digits value `\\D+`. I put this non-capturing group within the second capturing group resulting in `(\\D+(?:\\s\\D+)?)` as the first pattern `\\D+` is mandatory and the rest is optional and it matches both `Player Name` or `Trend` for example.

I defined two sets of columns in `names_to` argument so I had to define two capturing groups in `names_pattern` separated by a literal dot `.` as follows:

```
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(!`Trade Value`, names_to = c("Position", ".value"), 
               names_pattern = "(\\D+)\\.(\\D+(?:\\s\\D+)?)")

# A tibble: 120 x 4
   `Trade Value` Position      `Player Name`         Trend
           <dbl> <chr>         <chr>                 <dbl>
 1          79   Running Back  "Christian McCaffrey"     0
 2          79   Wide Receiver ""                       NA
 3          79   Tight End     ""                       NA
 4          79   Quarterback   ""                       NA
 5          70.5 Running Back  "Dalvin Cook"             0
 6          70.5 Wide Receiver ""                       NA
 7          70.5 Tight End     ""                       NA
 8          70.5 Quarterback   ""                       NA
 9          68.5 Running Back  "Alvin Kamara"            0
10          68.5 Wide Receiver ""                       NA
# ... with 110 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there any documentation you could refer me to to understand the regular expression needed for the pattern?

Comment: I will add some details to this answer to explain the regex I used, but you can download `basic regular expressions in R` & `stringr` cheat sheets from this link they are very concise and efficient: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Comment: @melmo I added a leaner version of the code suggested by dear Mr. Ruehlemann and also edited the first one a little, please check them.